# WooCommerce Display List of Products With Missing Attribute?

Tags: woocommerce, product

I've searched and searched but have not been able to find an answer to this, so thank you in advance for your help!

I am wanting to display a list (in the Admin portal, on the Products page) of all products that do NOT have a specific attribute assigned (so we can easily find products that need to be updated).

I have the same functionality already set up to display products that are missing other criteria (shipping class, weight, etc.) using a variation of this code and it works great, but I am not sure how to modify it to display products without the pa_sort-chassis attribute... so far, this is what I've got - it doesn't produce any results, though.

```
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'products_no_chassisattribute_admin' );
 
function products_no_chassisattribute_admin(){
    global $pagenow, $typenow;
    if ( 'edit.php' === $pagenow && 'product' === $typenow ) {
      echo '<div class="notice notice-warning is-dismissible"><h3>Products with NO Sort By Chassis Attribute</h3><ul>';
      $args = array(
         'status' => 'publish',
         'visibility' => 'visible',
         'limit' => -1
      );
      $products = wc_get_products( $args );
      foreach ( $products as $product ) {
         if ( ! $product = wc_get_products( array( 'pa_sort-chassis' => '' ) )) {
            echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( get_edit_post_link( $product->get_id() ) ) . '">' . $product->get_name() . '</a></li>';
         }
      }
      echo '</ul></div>';
    }
```

I modified the code I was already using but it does not produce any results

Answer (score 0):

The condition

```
if (! $product = wc_get_products(array('pa_sort-chassis' => '')))
```

will always evaluate to true because you are assigning a value to $product instead of checking its existence.

This will cause the loop to always execute the echo statement inside the if block.

```
function products_no_chassisattribute_admin() {
    global $pagenow, $typenow;
    if ( 'edit.php' === $pagenow && 'product' === $typenow ) {
        echo '<div class="notice notice-warning is-dismissible"><h3>Products with NO Sort By Chassis Attribute</h3><ul>';
        $args = array(
            'status' => 'publish',
            'visibility' => 'visible',
            'limit' => -1
        );
        $products = wc_get_products( $args );
        foreach ( $products as $product ) {
            $product_attributes = $product->get_attributes();
            if ( empty( $product_attributes['pa_sort-chassis'] ) ) {
                echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( get_edit_post_link( $product->get_id() ) ) . '">' . $product->get_name() . '</a></li>';
            }
        }
        echo '</ul></div>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To display products that do not have the **`"pa_sort-chassis"`** attribute assigned!

Please try this code and it should display the products that do not have the "pa_sort-chassis" attribute assigned in the Admin portal on the Products page.

```
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'products_no_chassisattribute_admin' );
function products_no_chassisattribute_admin() {
    global $pagenow, $typenow;
    if ( 'edit.php' === $pagenow && 'product' === $typenow ) {
        echo '<div class="notice notice-warning is-dismissible"><h3>Products with NO Sort By Chassis Attribute</h3><ul>';
        $args = array(
            'status'     => 'publish',
            'visibility' => 'visible',
            'limit'      => -1
        );
        $products = wc_get_products( $args );
        foreach ( $products as $product ) {
            $product_attributes = $product->get_attributes();
            if ( ! array_key_exists( 'pa_sort-chassis', $product_attributes ) ) {
                echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( get_edit_post_link( $product->get_id() ) ) . '">' . $product->get_name() . '</a></li>';
            }
        }
        echo '</ul></div>';
    }
}
```

Use the `get_attributes()` method to retrieve all the attributes of a product. Then, check if the key **`'pa_sort-chassis'`** exists in the `$product_attributes` array. If it doesn't exist, it means the product does not have the `"pa_sort-chassis"` attribute assigned, and it will be displayed in the list.